# MySQL select table column 31-12-2014 type varchar as date order by date php

Tags: php, html, mysql, date

Because of design I have a form with 3 select drop down menu (day, month and year) separated
I join the date before I save it to mysql using Post (d) Post m Post (Y) inserting the date like $d-$m-$Y fromt the form method post I save the date in a varchar 20 column joining d-m-Y and it saves fine

The date is displayed normal 30-10-2014

Now the problem is that in the search results page I want to search results between date A to B and get anything

Also while in search results I ORDER BY date the results I get are from any date

I dont know how to order or filter results using this kind of date saved in varchar here is what I am testing right now

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT product, price, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS new_date FROM `tableone` WHERE `user` = '$usernamefromform' ORDER BY `new_date` DESC Limit $start, $per_page");
```

How can I fix this without changing so much specially not my design please

Comment: Bad plan to store the date as a varchar. Now, when you want to use the data column as a Date, you have to deal with this every time. You saved yourself having to format it for display, but made more work doing anything else. That's backward -- you put the data into the database in structured *data* format, then change the format for display purposes if/when you display it. Rather than solve this specific problem (which can probably be done with `CAST` or the like), I would suggest you stop now and fix your database schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but before you define the `DATE_FORMAT` you need to convert your `VARCHAR` into a date. Further, you need to format the date in a way it can be properly sorted (thus only used by `ORDER BY`) but display it the way it is stored (if that's what you want):

```
SELECT product, price, date 
FROM `tableone` 
WHERE `user` = '$usernamefromform' 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y%m%d') DESC
```

Constructing a `BETWEEN` query with that is really bad (and probably slows everything down), but as you converted the `VARCHAR` to `DATE` you can now use following query:

```
SELECT product, price, date 
FROM `tableone`
WHERE `user` = '$usernamefromform' AND (date BETWEEN '2014-01-30' AND '2014-12-31')
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: This query solves the symptom but left the disease untreated. Varchar for dates is bad design, and should be fixed in the database. Otherwise he's going to have to pepper his code with this boilerplate any time he wants to sort or use `between`. Yuck.

Comment: That's absolutely right, I wouldn't encourage that solution, but OP writes it is by design, thus I am guessing he is maintaining an existing project and needs an answer for that.

Comment: Paul just a small question: Its filtering by date perfect but I dont know how to ger search results from between date to date

Comment: Well, just as Chris remarked, this is the wrong way because you need to use the construct everywhere. But you wrote that you changed the column from `VARCHAR` to `DATE`, how is your data stored now?

Comment: Changed from VARCHAR to DATE and first it was stored 31-12-2014 (d-m-Y) and I changed the way it stores is 2014-12-31 (Y-m-d) so maybe the new way I dont need date format anymore and mysql will find results without problems ? I am new with dates

Comment: Yes, if you changed it that way, you don't need that monster no more. Good job! - See updated answer for the new query.

Comment: I did it and worked just need a last thing I want to show the date like this because its stored Y-m-d and I need to show it like  <?php echo format($products['date']d-m-Y); ?> but this one is giving me errors

Comment: Like this? There is something missing I presume.

Comment: yeah must be, It must be wrong entirely but what I want is I always echo row like this <?php echo $row[productname]?> well I want a row like this containing the date to be formated Y-m-d but dont know how to do this

Comment: This is getting to long here. Your date column now is already set as Y-m-d. If you have problems with getting or displaying data, I'd suggest to open a new question.

Comment: @Grupo456436657 `<?=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($yourDateVariable))?>`

Comment: @Grupo456436657 Google "php.net [what you are trying to do]" and you'll get official documentation. Glad we could help, but you don't want to learn to depend on other people for all the answers, gotta learn my good man, gotta learn. Learning from mistakes, trial and error, and effective research are some of the most important tools a programmer can have.

Answer (score 1):

It's a really bad idea to store your dates in DD-MM-YYYY format in a varchar.  This prevents you from being able to order by the date or to search for a date between two dates.

If you change it to YYYY-MM-DD format and store it in a date field, it will solve all your problems :)